# Can a Scala for loop modify variables outside its scope?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have the following

```
  var lastSecurity = ""

  def allSecurities = for {
    security <- lastTrade.keySet.toList
    lastSecurity = security
  } yield security
```

At the moment

```
lastSecurity = security
```

Seems to be creating a new variable in scope rather than modifying the variable declared in the first line of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lastSecurity = ""

def allSecurities = for {
  security <- lastTrade.keySet.toList
} yield {
  lastSecurity = security
  security
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just like

```
var a = 1
{
  var a = 2
  println(a)
}
println(a)
```

which prints

```
2
1
```

It doesn't matter whether these are `var`s or `val`s. In Scala you're allowed to shadow variables from the outer scope, but this might lead to some confusion when you're exscused having to use the `val` keyword, i.e. for-comprehensions, anonymous functions and pattern matching.